# What kind of variable is model year of a vehicle?

Tags: classification, categorical-data, dataset

Model year doesn't necessarily indicate the calendar year it was manufactured in, so it isn't fully a measurement of time (except in a slightly fuzzier way than "calendar year of manufacture"). For example, the 2020 model of a vehicle often begins being delivered to customers in 2019 -- maybe even sometimes rolling off the assembly line in 2018 even. Of course each manufacturer likely has different practices in this regard. Of course, there is generally an ordering relationship that might be meaningful if restricted to a particular make or model of vehicle. This makes it feel like a categorical variable to me. The actual calendar year or time of manufacture would be numerical (interval) as would the actual physical age of a vehicle. Model year seems like it should be nominal as it really just part of the name of the vehicle model, but it does sort of indicate calendar year of manufacture in a very rough sense. That being said, model year is regulated by laws as well. If there were no regulation, then a manufacturer might decide to call their vehicles "2030 models" right now.

Finally, if you are using it to simply classify vehicles, then it is really categorical data. If you are using it as (a proxy for) vehicle age, then it feels like interval data.

Comment: Whatever 'model year'  actually is, in the minds of consumers, old model years are likely generally viewed as less desirable and probably priced lower. Exceptions probably exist where the styling (or engine size,...) in a select model year was considered exceptional.

Comment: @AJKOER So in terms of technology level, monetary value, model year is somewhat ordinal. I have trouble seeing it as truly interval though. I feel like it depends on how you are using it. If you are using it as a proxy for age then it is interval. If your are using it as a proxy for monetary value, then it is more ordinal. ?

Comment: Perhaps, one could consider the current and prior model's as ordinal, and older years as more interval like.

Comment: I guess as long as it reasonably signals the calendar year it was manufactured in, it is basically an interval variable (a somewhat coarse one at least).

Comment: Model year can be treated as any of the above.  See Lord, [On the Statistical Treatment of Football Numbers](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwjYqcaEm57tAhXmQzABHY1kDesQFjAAegQIAxAC&url=https%3A%2F%2Fweb.calpoly.edu%2F~glaver%2F333folder%2FLord.pdf&usg=AOvVaw12wCOZ0viYe9nv6qjBVZyx), for a stimulating discussion of some of the issues.

Comment: @whuber A fun illuminating story. Really I suppose classification doesn't matter unless it helps you figure out how to analyze the data and draw meaningful conclusions/inferences. That being said, I enjoy thinking about the classification -- kind of like a meta-stats/philosophical rabbit hole. Ultimately, anytime something is represented by a number, it's going to be treated like a number (by someone), and if that results in some kind of insight, then it's fine.

Comment: Both the first comment ("helps you figure out") and the last one ("some kind of insight') are well put.